# How to set a Key messages as Shared Resources for the presentation through Salesforce Veeva CRM interface?

Tags: salesforce

The documentation mentions as follows, however I do not see any of such checkboxes in Key Message properties. Any help would be appreciated. -Thanks

> To enable, ensure content admins have write access and users have read
>   access to these two fields on the
>
> Key Message object in CRM:
>
> **Is Shared Resource** – (Is_Shared_Resource_vod__c) is a check box that determines if a Key Message is a CLM shared resource
>   **Shared Resource** – (Shared_Resource_vod__ is a Look-up to the shared resources which the key message references

Answer (score 4):

In addition to masmrdrr's answer and as response to hey_suburbia's comment ...

**How to make the fields visible:**

---

1. Go to any key message detail page and click the *Edit Layout* link:

[image]

---

2. Drag and drop the *Is Shared Resource* and *Shared Resource* fields to the layout where you wish to have them placed and click the save button:

[image]

---

3. Go to the *Setup* page by clicking the dropdown with your username:

[image]

---

4. Search for `Field Accessibility`, then from the list at right hand click the *Key Message* link:

[image]

---

5. Click *View by Profiles*, select the profile you want to edit (e.g. *Content Viewer* or *System Administrator*) and click the corresponding link in the *Field Access* column:

[image]

---

6. Finally check/uncheck the checkboxes as neeed and click the save button:

[image]

---

Answer (score 2):

Using your Veeva admin ID, you'll have to enable both the red highlighted field options on your Key Message interface/view. After which, when you're uploading your Shared Zip, you'll have to check the box labelled "Is Shared Resource".

[image: Sample Veeva Key Message Shared Resource]

Simultaneously, every ZIP you upload, you'll have to enter the ZIP name in the "Shared Resource" input box.